# Magento 2 - Remove Fotorama Caption from Product View Page

Tags: magento2, layout

[image: Image Label on Product View]

I need to remove the image label/name from product view pages, or determine why they're showing up. I cannot seem to find them referenced in the XML for catalog_product_view.xml, nor in the phtml files.

I searched here and google for this but did not find anything substantial. I can't even find anything related. On this install, I am using the Ultimo theme by Infortis and Magento is version 2.2.4.

The attached screenshot displays what I mean. The image file name is displayed under the image and I need to remove that, but have found nothing in the way of assistance.

[EDIT] It's the Fotorama caption I need to remove. The view.xml for Ultimo has these set to false but they're still not being removed. I tried removing it through the CSS .less files but no go. Flushed caches between all changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not currently a way to remove with admin panel options or layout xml update. Easiest thing to do is just set a display:none property.

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .catalog-product-view {
        .fotorama__caption {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which .less file should I use? Will any of them work?

Comment: Any of them should work. However, from an organizational standpoint, I like to put general product page changes in Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/layout/_catalog_category_view.less. But that's just personal preference.

Comment: I added it to my theme's _custom.less and flushed the cache but no change. Still in developer mode so I shouldn't need to deploy static content. Would it be worth doing that?

Comment: Delete your var/view_preprocessed directory and your pub/static/frontend/Your/theme and then refresh the page. It would also be a good idea to flush your browser cache but you may not need to.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property "showCaption" which is set to true by default in fotorama.js
You can set this to false from gallery.phtml

Answer (score 2):

It's Fairly easy though. Override view.xml file in your theme, 
Find:

```
<var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title in fullscreen(true/false) -->
```

Enable - Disable by true/false, Clear Cache and see the results.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand on Popa's answer. The issue with the configuration file (`app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/etc/view.xml`) not working is because to the value checks that happen all over the file

```
file: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
     "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
```

Because the value for `$block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")` will be false when set to false in the config file, this option (`showCaption`) will never show up on the page when the template is rendered. So it defaults back to to the core JS files settings (found in `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`).

This is just some bad coding, so there is a way to set the option to show but no way to set it to false.

So the correct way to set this is to copy the `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` to your theme and anywhere in the `options` JS object place the setting as you like it, with no php conditional check.

```
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
            "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
            "options": {
                ...
                "showCaption": false,
                ...
            },
            "fullscreen": {
                ...
                "showCaption": false,
                ...
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this file gallery.phtml for your theme write in the css 
    .fotorama__caption {
        display: none;
    }